# Add values in certain rows to another row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cohort': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    'age': [-1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
    'bal': [100, 1000, 1400, 1500, 1000, 1200, 1300]
})
```

Where applicable, I want to add `bal` where `age` is less than 0 to the `bal` values where `age` is zero for each `cohort`. Ultimately I want df to look like this:

```
df
  cohort age  bal
1      1  -1  100
2      1   0 1100
3      1   1 1400
4      1   2 1500
5      2   0 1000
6      2   1 1200
7      2   2 1300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how `pandas` will achieve it

```
df.loc[df.age==0, 'bal']= df.loc[df.age==0, 'bal']+ df.loc[df.age<0, 'bal'].values
df
Out[339]: 
   age   bal  cohort
0   -1   100       1
1    0  1100       1
2    1  1400       1
3    2  1500       1
4   -1   120       2
5    0  1120       2
6    1  1200       2
7    2  1300       2
```

Update  :

```
df.loc[df.age==0, 'bal']=df.loc[df.age<=0].groupby('cohort').bal.sum().values
```

Comment: Sorry, how about the case when all `cohort` values do not see an `age` of -1? I updated the question to reflect this. In this case the R code doesn't work either.